# How to do code format switching in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

A)

```
public class SomeClass
{

 private SomeClass()
  {
  }

  public String someMethod()
  {
   return "";
  }
}
```

B)

```
public class SomeOtherClass{

    private SomeOtherClass(){
    }

   public String someOtherMethod(){
     return "";
   }
 }
```

I have joined a new team and will be working on a project which follows the A) convention. However, I have always been the B) java style person and am way more comfortable with B).

1)On the checked out code, is there a way I could convert the java code style in my eclipse to B)

2)And also ensure the project->Team->Synch with Repo ignores this style change when checking for updates ?

3)Before comitting, I want to switch the code back to the commonly followed style and check it in. I synch for changes every morning and commit changes throughout the day.

Is creating a new profile in the preferences->code style->Formatter the only way ? I also looked at http://astyle.sourceforge.net/ but I am somehow confident there is a simpler eclipse solution to this. How could I achieve this in the simplest possible way ?
I am using eclipse kepler

Comment: Which SCM are you using?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK SVN (Tortoise)

Comment: Check whether SVN supports calling actions(programs) after checkout and before commit. If it provides some hooks the try to develop the script.

Answer (score 1):

Work flow:

1. In `Windows > Preferences > Java > Editors Save Actions` deselect formatting on save.
2. Check out code.
3. Clean up your code(Right click on project go to `Source > Clean up`. Note this works on project level but not on working set, so you have to do it on each and every project) with your Formatter(**B**) profile enabled.
4. In `Windows > Preferences > Java > Editors Save Actions` select formatting on save and start working.
5. Same as step 1.
6. Same as 3 but with formatter profile **A**.
7. Commit the code.

These steps can be automated with Ant/Maven script(?) or by developing your own eclipse plug-in.

On sync comparator will NOT ignore style change. IMHO there is no escape. Clean up before sync is only the go.

In Git SCM there are some commit and checkout hooks but I haven't explored on this.